# cast as decimal using sums

Tags: sql, decimal

Hi I have this query....

```
select count (tarjetas), Programa, avg(ticketprom), sum (tickets),
(cast(sum (tickets)/
(sum(mesesdecompra) as decimal) as frec
from #tabla1
group by Programa
```

column *Tickets* has integer numbers and *mesesdecompra* too, what I want is to have the result in decimals and also create another column named frec.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this (casting of operand, instead of result):

```
select
    count (tarjetas),
    Programa,
    avg(ticketprom),
    sum (tickets),
    cast(sum(tickets) as decimal)/sum(mesesdecompra) as frec
from #tabla1
group by Programa
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me.